# Share data using WCSession between apple Watch and iPhone

Tags: objective-c, watchos

Trying to share data from iPhone to apple watch using updateApplicationContext, transferUserInfo of Watch connectivity (WCSession) working in simulator but when trying same on device but its not working.

Device : iPhone 6 plus(OS 11.1), apple watch-Series 2(Watch OS 4.1).

Working on defaultSession and implemented necessary delegate methods for watchConnectivity.

iPhone side :

step : 1

```
if ([WCSession isSupported])
{
    [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate:self];
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}
```

step : 2

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] transferUserInfo:dataDict];
```

Apple Watch side : Working on defaultSession
step : 1

```
if ([WCSession isSupported])
{
    [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate:self];
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}
```

step : 2

```
   -(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)userInfo
    {
       // code for data parsing which get from userInfo dictionary.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for my project

After setting session and creating data dictionary you use send message with this

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:dataDict replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {

        //You task on completion

    } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (error)
        {
            //Handle the error
        }
    }];
```

And in watch app code
You can set delegate method

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler
{
}
```

And you are done

Comment: thank u for reply..i have tried above solution but its not working on the real device too.